# How does Annotate F() on ForeignKey work?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a very simple test project with the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='pizzas')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

For test purpose, I created 4 instances of "Pizza", all with the same Category:

```
'Test Pizza'
'Test'
'Another One'
'Yoplahihou'
```

Here is a simple code and its result:

```
[print(p.id, p) for p in Pizza.objects.all()]

1 Test Pizza
2 Test
3 Another one
4 Yoplahihou
```

Up to this point everything is fine. A simple modification to this code to add an annotate gives:

```
[print(p.id, p, "| test:", p.test) for p in Pizza.objects.annotate(test=F('category'))]

1 Test Pizza | test: 1
2 Test | test: 1
3 Another one | test: 1
4 Yoplahihou | test: 1
```

Still good, (they all belong to the category with id 1). But where I completely lose it is with the following result:

```
[print(p.id, p, "| test:", p.test) for p in Pizza.objects.annotate(test=F('category__pizzas'))]

1 Test Pizza | test: 1
1 Test Pizza | test: 2
1 Test Pizza | test: 3
1 Test Pizza | test: 4
2 Test | test: 1
2 Test | test: 2
2 Test | test: 3
2 Test | test: 4
3 Another one | test: 1
3 Another one | test: 2
3 Another one | test: 3
3 Another one | test: 4
4 Yoplahihou | test: 1
4 Yoplahihou | test: 2
4 Yoplahihou | test: 3
4 Yoplahihou | test: 4
```

Could someone please explain to me what is going on? Why do I end up with so many additional results in the query and why is the value of "test" different for each of them?

This is a simple example, but I am trying to reproduce this on a much more complicated query for another project and I absolutely don't have this multiplication of the results (but I am trying to obtain it). If I could understand what is going on here, I could maybe figure out what to do in my other project.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? This seems like the standard behaviour of SQL; you're joining on a multi-value field, so you're going to get multiple rows in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query :

```
[print(p.id, p, "| test:", p.test) for p in Pizza.objects.annotate(test=F('category'))]
```

You select the pizza and join the category.

In the second one :

```
[print(p.id, p, "| test:", p.test) for p in Pizza.objects.annotate(test=F('category__pizzas'))]
```

You select the pizza and join the category (like the the first one), and join
the category to the pizza associate. 
The category 1 is associate with pizza 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
Category 1 | Pizza 1
Category 1 | Pizza 2
Category 1 | Pizza 3
Category 1 | Pizza 4
```

So back to the second query, for line one :

```
1 Test Pizza | Category 1
```

There is 4 lines associated.

Give you :

```
1 Test Pizza | test: 1
1 Test Pizza | test: 2
1 Test Pizza | test: 3
1 Test Pizza | test: 4
```

Same for the other line from table pizza.

Ps: sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can use the F() function to multiply two fields:

```
from django.db.models import F

books = Book.objects.annotate(total_price=F('unit_price') * F('inventory'))
```

In this example, we're using the annotate() function to create a new field called total_price which is the product of the unit_price and inventory fields.

If you want to multiply a local field with a foreign key field, you can use the double underscore syntax to access the foreign key field:

```
books = Book.objects.annotate(total_price=F('unit_price') * F('discount__value'))
```

In this example, we're using the discount__value syntax to access the value field of the discount foreign key.

Keep in mind that the fields you're multiplying must be of compatible types (i.e. both integers or both decimals) in order for the multiplication to work. If you're still having issues, please provide more information on the fields you're trying to multiply together and any error messages you're receiving.